# PHP Syntax Check in Sublime Text Editor

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin, syntax-checking

In Gedit, I can add an External Tool of "php -l" on the current document, and if I have PHP command line installed, it will syntax check the document. Is there a way to do this with Sublime Text Editor? (Note, I have a Mac and it has PHP CLI installed.)

I imagine I'll have to paste a code snippet into Sublime plugin, right?

Comment: A queck check of google reveals: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Syntax%20Checker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The action you are referring to is called "linting" and there are a number of plugins for Sublime that lint PHP files. As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433423/php-syntax-check-in-sublime-text-editor#comment37805613_24433423) by Len_D, [`PHP Syntax Checker`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Syntax%20Checker) is one, but I'd actually recommend [`SublimeLinter` for Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2) instead. (There is a different version of `SublimeLinter` for ST3, but it's not backwards-compatible, and has a completely different architecture than the ST2 version, which is no longer officially supported.)

To install, first [install Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) if you haven't already, then restart Sublime. Open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type ***`pci`*** to bring up `Package Control: Install Package`. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type in ***`sublimelinter`***, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to install. After installation is complete, restart ST2 again for good luck. To configure, first open **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings-Default`** and copy its entire contents. Then, open **`Settings-User`** from the same sub-menu and paste the contents into it. You can now close **`Settings-Default`**. For proper syntax highlighting (to tell where the comments are), select **`JavaScript -> JSON`** from the option list in the lower right of the Sublime window.

Scroll down to line 36 in the `"sublimelinter_executable_map"` dict and add a blank line between the opening `{` and closing `}` braces. Find the full path to the `php` executable on your system by opening Terminal and typing `which php`. Copy the path and add an entry for `"php"` on the blank line you just made. For example, if the path is `/opt/local/bin/php`, the full section should look like this:

```json
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
    "php": "/opt/local/bin/php"
},
```

Scroll down through the rest of the `"sublimelinter_*"` options and modify them to suit your preferences. The options after line 108 are most likely irrelevant for you, as they deal with linters for JavaScript, CSS, Python, etc. However, feel free to read through them in case you'd like to use `SublimeLinter` for other languages.
Once you're done, save the file and you should be all set. `SublimeLinter` will display its messages according to the `"sublimelinter"` (line 13) and `"sublimelinter_delay"` settings (line 67) (increase the value to increase the delay between stopping typing and linter messages appearing). If you don't want this "live" linting, set `"sublimelinter"` to `load-save`, `save-only`, or `false`, depending on your preferences. I personally find live linting to be rather annoying...

And that's about it. Full documentation is available in the [README](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/blob/master/README.md). Please keep in mind that if/when you upgrade to [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3) (which I highly recommend, by the way), you'll need to install and configure [`SublimeLinter3`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter), which is a complete re-write of the plugin into a more modular architecture. As such, the base `SublimeLinter` package must be supplemented by a language-specific linter plugin like [`SublimeLinter-php`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-php). Please ensure you read the [full documentation](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (yes, there's a lot, but it's worth it) to get everything running smoothly.

Good luck!

Comment: I installed this on Sublime Text 2 on Windows 7 and I didn't need to change any settings. Nice.